# tricky sql query for the given table

Tags: mysql, sql

given a table similar to the one below

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+--------------+
| name        | continent | area    | population | gdp          |
| Afghanistan | Asia      | 652230  | 25500100   | 20343000000  |
| Albania     | Europe    | 28748   | 2831741    | 12960000000  |
| Algeria     | Africa    | 2381741 | 37100000   | 188681000000 |
| Andorra     | Europe    | 468     | 78115      | 3712000000   |
| Angola      | Africa    | 1246700 | 20609294   | 100990000000 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+--------------+
```

What is the query needed to  get the following result.

Some countries have populations more than three times that of any of their neighbors (in the same continent). Give the countries and continents.

**EDIT**

This is what i have tried so far.

```
SELECT name, continent FROM 
world x
WHERE x.name = ALL(SELECT name FROM world y where y.continent = x.continent and (x.population/y.population) > 3)
```

The above query does not return any records :(

And to add this is not home work. I am trying to brush up SQL for back end developer interview.(have not used SQL for a while instead used object relational mapping frameworks)

Comment: what have your tried? home work should be done on your own

Comment: If you've not tried anything yet, then hint: Sort by continent and population, then compare the top 2 records in each group.

Comment: add more data and your desired output

Comment: If I get you right, than you want any country for a continent that has a population of at least 3 times the population of the country in that continent with the lowest population? "Neighbor" is not possible with your data.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This query**

```
SELECT name, continent
FROM countries x
WHERE x.population > ALL (SELECT population * 3 FROM countries y WHERE x.continent = y.continent AND x.name <> y.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:-

```
SELECT name, continent FROM world where name not in(
   SELECT name FROM world a where name =
     ALL(SELECT name FROM world b where a.continent =b.continent and a.population>b.population*3)
)
```